# How to set custom font to sherlock's contextual action bar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I know how to set a custom font to the action bar. I just have to extend SherlockFragmentActivity and override setTitle like this:

```
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    String str = String.valueOf(title);
    str = str.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(str);
    MetricAffectingSpan span = new MetricAffectingSpan() {
        @Override
        public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
            p.setTypeface(FontManager.INSTANCE.getAppFont());
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
            tp.setTypeface(FontManager.INSTANCE.getAppFont());
        }
    };

    s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
}
```

However, things get complicated with a contextual action bar. The library uses a factory to return the contextual action bar, like this:

```
ActionMode mode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
mode.setTitle("whatever");
```

I COULD override ActionMode, yet the lib won't return it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see is a little bit complex...

You will need to create a `View` where you will place your `TextView` as the title, set the font you want for this `TextView`, and use `setCustomView` to place your view with the new font.

I hope it helps you.

**UPDATE**

Have you tried create your own method, like this:

```
public void setActionModeTitle(CharSequence title) {
    String str = String.valueOf(title);
    str = str.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(str);
    MetricAffectingSpan span = new MetricAffectingSpan() {
        @Override
        public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
            p.setTypeface(FontManager.INSTANCE.getAppFont());
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
            tp.setTypeface(FontManager.INSTANCE.getAppFont());
        }
    };

    s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    actionMode.setTitle(s);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to change only the textview used for the title?

Comment: Edit 2 worked! i had tried that earlier, to no avail. It was quite simple after all. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_very_small"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uRecomendTitleText"
        style="@style/TitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:text="@string/recommendation"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/TitleStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_very_small"
            android:text="@string/rank" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uRecomendCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_box"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.uRecomendTitleText);
     Typeface AshtonsHand;
        AshtonsHand = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                IConstants.font);
    txt.setTypeface(AshtonsHand);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bg_back));

    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.friends_list_actionbar);
```